# Applescript -- osx mail -- make some words bold if a paragraph starts with a 3 digit number

Tags: macos, email, formatting, applescript

I have an applescript that automatically generates an email. Previously, the script was looking for any paragraph that started with "Ep" and making the first two words of that paragraph bold.

But now, the email body has changed. We are dropping the "Ep" portion(s) from the email body, so I want to make the first two words of any paragraph that starts with a **three digit number** bold. I've searched around, but I don't know exactly how to get applescript to look for a **paragraph** starting ANY three digit number.

Previous code was (essentially):

```
tell application "Mail"
    activate
    
    set emailSubject to (" Daily Reports") as rich text
    set emailContent to ("Ep123 - XYZ: This is just an example
    This line shouldn't be bold
    
Ep980 - ABC: This is a second example")
    
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:emailSubject, content:emailContent}
    
    tell theMessage
        set font of (words 1 thru 2 of (every paragraph where the first word starts with "Ep")) to "Helvetica Bold"
        
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"test@example.com"}
    end tell
end tell
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the script like so:

```
tell application "Mail"
    activate
    
    set emailSubject to (" Daily Reports") as rich text
    set emailContent to ("123 some text 
724: some text
some random text
645Fgz: and more text")
    
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:emailSubject, content:emailContent}
    
    tell theMessage
        repeat with a_paragraph in paragraphs
            set lead_in to (characters 1 through 4 of a_paragraph) as rich text
            ignoring punctuation and hyphens
                considering numeric strings
                    if lead_in > 99 and lead_in < 1000 then
                        set font of (words 1 thru 2 of a_paragraph) to "Helvetica Bold"
                    end if
                end considering
            end ignoring
        end repeat
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"test@example.com"}
    end tell
end tell
```

This changes the font of the first two words in the paragraph when the first three characters are numbers and the forth character is a letter, whitespace, or punctuation mark. it won't catch numbers beginning with 0 (e.g. 050).

Note that if you're using dark mode, this script also changes the font color, for some reason. You might need to address that.

Comment: Thanks for this!  After a bit of testing (and goal post moving), I noticed that two line breaks in a row will cause an index error.  I wound up adding try / end try around the "set lead_in" line. Works perfectly.